# How to use AND in R to modify dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data matrix 1200 (row, sample name)* 20000 (col, gene name), I want to delete row when my interested 5 genes have zero values in all samples

command I used for single gene:

```
allexp <-preallexp[preallexp$GZMB > 0, ]
```

but I want to use AND in above command, like this:

```
allexp <-preallexp[preallexp$GZMB && preallexp$TP53 && preallexp$EGFR && preallexp$BRAF && preallexp$VGEF > 0, ]
```

but this command doesnt work, please I need your help..How to use AND in above command.

Comment: `&&` returns only the first logical result of the condition, you should use `&` (single ampersand) also you should repeat the condition every time i.e. `preallexp$GZMB > 0 & preallexp$TP53 > 0 & ...`

Comment: Thanks,  digEmAll, But I want if sum of 5 gene is zero, then delete row, sorry I didnt mentioned in above.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: in response to OP.
I'm sure there's a much more efficient way to code this, but this is what you're after:

```
allexp <-preallexp[preallexp$GZMB + preallexp$TP53 + preallexp$EGFR + 
                     preallexp$BRAF + preallexp$VGEF > 0, ]
```

Comment: Thanks mkt, this code just delete row whene each gene has 0 values, But I want to delete row if sum of 5 genes in row is zero.

Comment: Odd. Can you could post a reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have negative expression values I would have thought mkt's should work. But here is mine. It will remove values rows where each of the 5 genes and a value of 0

```
which(preallexp$GZMB == 0 && preallexp$TP53 && 
 preallexp$EGFR == 0 && preallexp$BRAF == 0 && preallexp$VGEF == 0)
```

This gives so the rows where all 5 genes have a value of zero

So we can remove these rows if from the dataframe like follows

```
allexp <-preallexp[
   -(which(preallexp$GZMB == 0 && preallexp$TP53 && 
     preallexp$EGFR == 0 && preallexp$BRAF == 0 && preallexp$VGEF == 0)), ]
```